# ARM development and emulation

Tags: debian, arm, cross-compiling, emulation

I have an ARM device (network storage) with debian installed. I can pull out drive and dump fs image (using dd). The OS there is debian, I use ubuntu.

What do I need to install (software) to be able to cross-compile?

I can mount image and modify its content.
How can I emulate that device to test cross-compiled executables?

**UPDATE**:
I don't mean any assembler programming, what I want is compile some usual debian daemons (web-server + scripts) and deploy after check.

Comment: Huh, super-users will worry about cross-compiling?

Comment: Definitely not a coding issues, more suited for superuser.com I believe.

Comment: The question is about compiling and testing compiled code, this is not superuser question.

Answer (score 1):

check this out:http://www.embeddedarm.com/software/software-arm-linux.php

they have cross toolchains for linux and cygwin.

There are Arm emulators out there, but if you are trying to emulate the entire board, that may be a diffrent story..

I have had the best luck by using a development pc with cross toolchain to develop and compile, and then nfs mounting my development directory on the Single board computer.

Answer (score 1):

`code sourcery` or `emdebian` if that doesn't work.